# customising first level and sub level of a menu separatly

Tags: css, wordpress, html-lists, menuitem

I'm using a menu in wordpress, using wp-menu.
it generates my menu automaticaly. I can then customize my menu with css.
I'm trying to customize separatly my first level li, and all the sub level li.
for example, I've would like to apply a padding left of 20 px in my first level, and no padding in the sub level.

In this case, I've added this code to add content after the 3rd element of my first level menu, but it is added alors to all my sub level menu...

```
ul#menu-menu_top li:nth-child(3):after{content:" | ";color:yellow}
```

here is my CSS :

```
.menu-menu_top-container{background-color: #1C2336}

ul#menu-menu_top, ul#menu-menu_top ul.sub-menu {
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
}
ul#menu-menu_top li, ul#menu-menu_top ul.sub-menu li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
ul#menu-menu_top li:nth-child(3):after{content:" | ";color:yellow}

/*Link Appearance*/
ul#menu-menu_top li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    display:inline-block;

    padding-left: 20px;
}

ul#menu-menu_top li {
    position: relative;
}

ul#menu-menu_top li ul.sub-menu {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
}

ul#menu-menu_top li ul.sub-menu li a{background-color: white;color:#1C2336;width:300px;}
ul#menu-menu_top li ul.sub-menu li a:hover{background-color: #1C2336;color: white}

ul#menu-menu_top li:hover ul.sub-menu {
    display:block;
}
```

and a jsfiddle with my html :

http://jsfiddle.net/JpqNs/

can anybody help me with this ?
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This can be simply solved by using the `>` CSS selector. For example, if you had the following code:

```
<ul class="layer1">
    <li>
        Link
    </li>
    <li>
        Link
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul class="layer2">
            <li>
                Link
            </li>
            <li>
                Link
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You can use the CSS `.layer1>li{YourStylesHere}` to only affect the li elements that are direct children of your layer1 `<ul>`. This will not affect children of children, such as the `<li>` elements of your layer2 `<ul>`

Comment: thanks @Hiigaran. In my case I can use #menu-menu_top > li to target all li from my first level, but what do I use to get all lis from my sublevel menu ? I'm trying #menu-menu_top > .sub-menu > li but it's not working... thanks a lot

Comment: You just use `.sub-menu>li{styles;}`. Using your fiddle, I removed `background-color:white;` from `ul#menu-menu_top li ul.sub-menu li a`, and added `.sub-menu>li{background:red;}`, which works just fine. Also, you don't need to use multiple layers of `>` selectors unless you actually need to be that specific. If you have something that doesn't work because of this, it's likely because you have some other CSS that blocks or overwrites it.